# Java hibernate JPA error with JUnit Testing

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am using hibernate in my Java EE application in combination with my Wildfly server to persist my Classes in a mysql Database. 
So far this works fine but now I am writing unit tests and I am getting crazy about some error which I get.

I would like to test my DAO-Layer in my Unit-Tests but I get these errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:/MySqlDS]
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

my persistence.xml ist this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.se.bac.data.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb?useSSL=false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="student"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="student"/>


            <!-- 
                SQL stdout logging 
            --> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

So, Here I am using a jta-data-source> as you can see.

If I remove this line my tests are going fine! But I can not build my project with maven anymore.

```
Error:
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"}}
```

He can not find the datasource because I removed the line in my persistence.xml

How can I manage to get both run in my application. The tests and of course the maven build?

Here is my test: (Setup is already causing the error):

```
package org.se.bac.data.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.se.bac.data.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAOTest
{
    private static final JdbcTestHelper JDBC_HELPER = new JdbcTestHelper();
    private final static JpaTestHelper JPA_HELPER = new JpaTestHelper();

    private EntityManager em = JPA_HELPER.getEntityManager("primary");
    private EmpDAO dao;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init()
    {

        JDBC_HELPER.executeSqlScript("sql/test/dropEmployeeTable.sql"); 
        JDBC_HELPER.executeSqlScript("sql/test/createEmployeeTable.sql");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy()
    {
        //JDBC_HELPER.executeSqlScript("sql/test/dropEmployeeTable.sql");       
    }


    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        JDBC_HELPER.executeSqlScript("sql/test/dropEmployeeTable.sql"); 
        JDBC_HELPER.executeSqlScript("sql/test/createEmployeeTable.sql");
        dao = new EmpDAOImpl();     
        dao.setEm(em);

        JPA_HELPER.txBegin();


        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setFirstname("Max");
        emp2.setLastname("Muster");
        emp2.setHiredate("23-12-1991");

        dao.insert(emp2);
    }
```

And JPAHELPER Class:

```
package org.se.bac.data.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class JpaTestHelper 
{
    /*
     * Property: persistenceUnitName
     */
    private String persistenceUnitName;
    public String getPersistenceUnitName()
    {
        return persistenceUnitName;
    }
    public void setPersistenceUnitName(String persistenceUnitName)
    {
        if(persistenceUnitName == null || persistenceUnitName.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal parameter persistenceUnitName = " + persistenceUnitName);
        this.persistenceUnitName = persistenceUnitName;
    }


    /*
     * Get an instance of the EntityManagerFactory.
     */
    protected EntityManagerFactory getEnityManagerFactory()
    {
        if(persistenceUnitName == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("PersistenceUnitName must be set!");
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
    }


    /*
     * Manage an EntityManager.
     */

    private EntityManager em;
    public EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        if(em == null)
        {
            em = getEnityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        }
        return em;          
    }
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(String persistenceUnitName)
    {
        setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
        return getEntityManager();          
    }


    public void closeEntityManager()
    {
        if(em != null)
            em.close();
    }


    /*
     * Handle Transactions 
     */

    protected void txBegin()
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
    }

    protected void txCommit()
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        if(tx.getRollbackOnly())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        else
        {
            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    protected void txRollback()
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

and my DAO:

```
package org.se.bac.data.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.se.bac.data.model.Employee;

class EmpDAOImpl // package private
        implements EmpDAO
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /*
     * CRUD methods
     */


    public Employee findById(int id)
    {
        System.out.println("empdaoimpl ID " + id);
        return em.find(Employee.class, id);
    }






    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }





}
```

Wildfly Datasource:

```
   <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb?useSSL=false</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>student</user-name>
                    <password>student</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
```

Comment: You are executing your Unittest in a so called non-managed environment. So there is no datasource and no Wildfly. Either you create a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence.xml or you use Arquillian for testing. Tell my what you prefer and I show you the way to do that.

Comment: Hello, Thanks fpr your answer! It would be great if you could give me some hints regarding RESOURCE_LOCAL! Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/

Answer (score 2):

> He can not find the datasource because I removed the line in my persistence.xml
>
> How can I manage to get both run in my application.

The problem is that the data source is managed by Wildfly which is not available on your test environment. So what you could do is define two separate persistence units (one for your production code and the other for the test) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        
            <!--  SQL stdout logging --> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>org.se.bac.data.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb?useSSL=false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="student"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="student"/>


            <!--   SQL stdout logging  --> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

 </persistence>
```

and then in your `EmployeeDAOTest` class modify the following line as:

```
private EntityManager em = JPA_HELPER.getEntityManager("testPU");
```

Note:

- I removed the JDBC connection properties from the `primary` persistence unit because you don't need them as you already have the data source there on Wildfly.